# Is it ok to put the main loop of a program in the constructor of a class?

Tags: c++

I am making a Bomberman game, and it needs a "main loop" where the game updates constantly. Here's basically what I did :

```
class BomberMan {
    public:
        BomberMan()
        {
            Init_BomberMan();
            while (RayLib::ShouldWindowClose()) {
                // game updates things
            }
        }
    private:
        Init_BomberMan()
        {
            // init data, load sprites, do things
        }
};

int main ()
{
    try {
        BomberMan();
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is putting the loop in the constructor of BomberMan class ok ?
Or is it better and cleaner to put it out of the constructor and do things differently ?

Comment: Well, you can tell yourself whether it works or not. On top of that, the rest is only opinions. That said, it looks like a function call. Now, what if you turned the class into a function? I guess you could save some code, which is usually a good thing. Simpler is often better. That said, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Question is opionion based. I would still put the loop in a seperate method, might help you with unit testing. There is probably other aspects of the game you want to test seperately (like loading data) and then having clearly named functions with only one responsibility really helps.

Comment: I try to use a constructor just for the construction of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty bad to do so.

The constructor is supposed to initialize the class. So having a function `Init_BomberMan` shows that you don't understand what a constructor is for. That function should be the constructor and probably nothing else.

And then you should have a function that runs your game, lets call that `run` as is so often used:

```
class BomberMan {
    public:
        void run()
        {
            while (RayLib::ShouldWindowClose()) {
                // game updates things
            }
        }
        BomberMan()
        {
            // init data, load sprites, do things
        }
};

int main ()
{
    try {
        BomberMan().run();
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The biggest reason for this, besides bad style, is that exception handling in constructors is a pain. Also calling other functions of the class in the constructor is fishy. You can do that if you are careful and only use members of the class that have already been initialized and such. Keep your constructors simple. The best constructor is an empty one, only topped by not needing one at all.

Use member initialization lists in the constructor or inline initialization of the members.